# How to monitor the changes in the Bluetooth Connectivity state changes from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Need to check the bluetooth connection to a remote device exists or got disconnected. Its basically a Forms which mainly targets Android and UWP.

I tried with the Dependency services and made the implementation in Android as below,

```
    _[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(BluetoothListenerActivity))]
namespace demotool.Droid
{
public class BluetoothListenerActivity : Activity,IBluetoothListener
{
public event EventHandler OnDeviceDisconnected;
public static BluetoothListenerActivity mySelf;

    //string device;
    public void start()
    {
        mySelf = this;
        BluetoothStatusBroadCast mreceiver = new BluetoothStatusBroadCast();
        IntentFilter mfilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected);
        Forms.Context.RegisterReceiver(mreceiver,mfilter);
    }
    public void receivedstatuschangd(string devicename,string state)
    {
        OnDeviceDisconnected(this, new DeviceDisconnectedEventArgs(name: devicename,status: state));
    }
}
}_

BroadcastReceiver: 
namespace Demo.Droid
{
[BroadcastReceiver]
class BluetoothStatusBroadCast : BroadcastReceiver 
{
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
BluetoothDevice device =(BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
BluetoothListenerActivity.mySelf.receivedstatuschangd(device.Name, intent.Action);
}
}
}

Xamarin Forms Part:
_ protected override void OnStart()
{
IBluetoothListener bluetoothlistener = DependencyService.Get();
bluetoothlistener.start();
bluetoothlistener.OnDeviceDisconnected += Bluetoothlistener_OnDeviceDisconnected;
}
private void Bluetoothlistener_OnDeviceDisconnected(object sender, DeviceDisconnectedEventArgs e)
{
Page page1 = new Page();
page1.DisplayAlert(e.Name+ " " +e.Status, "Alert", "OK");
}_
```

The Intent Action that I have registered- BluetoothDevice.ActionAclDisconnected, is getting triggered once the Pairing is completed or a connection request is made, which I assume is not the actual Disconnection of the devices

Is there any common plugin which monitors the Bluetooth Connectivity Changes to a remote device. Or could you please tell me the actual Intent Action that I should listen for.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, does any one has a solution for this